# Find which promises aren't resolving?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have an array of promises `promises = [p1,p2,p3]` however, one or more aren't resolving and so `Promise.all(promises)` never finishes and just keeps waiting.

How can I console.log every time each individual promise resolves (perhaps with the array index) so that I can find the one(s) that aren't resolving?

Comment: `Promise.all(promises.map((p, i) => p.then((value) => (console.log("resolved " + i), value))))`?

Comment: if it's for debug purposes only, you can await any single promise individually and see what has the problem

Comment: You can use something like this and print it to the console.
const p = Promise.all([1,2,3]);
console.log(p);
Use a setTimeout for the console if required.

Comment: @AkshayRaut that's pointless because the values in your example _aren't_ promises, and the OP is _already_ using `Promise.all` which won't resolve until and unless all promises in it resolve.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over all promises and wait for each individual promise to resolve.

```js
const p1 = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'p1'));
const p2 = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000, 'p2'));
const p3 = new Promise(resolve => {/* never resolve */});

const promises = [p1, p2, p3];

promises.forEach((p, i) => {
  p.then((value) => {console.log('Promise at index %i resolved with %o', i, value);});
});
```